# Office 365 issues while trying to impersonate using unlicensed user

Tags: office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, impersonation

We're using exchange impersonation to access office 365 accounts mailboxes, usually customers provide us technical users that are not licensed (to not pay for its license). And everything was fine up to 5 days ago, something chnaged in office 365 behavior and in many our customers we started to get exception : "The account does not have permission to impersonate the requested user."
Nothing was changed in account settings (user didn't do anything) and nothing changed in our code. 
Is there any possible way to workaround such issue (expect adding license for that user)?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to find a workaround and this is actually EWS programming, so... Why it's not about programming ? And also, in some our discussion with Office 365 people, they suggest us always ask here.